# Missing last item on enums

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, enums

I was looking for some enums options, and just spotted a missing comma after last option. Take, for instance, that `DayOfWeek` enum (press `F12` to go to definition):

```
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday    = 0,
    Monday    = 1,
    Tuesday   = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday  = 4,
    Friday    = 5,
    Saturday  = 6, // note this comma
}
```

Are there any reason behind this behavior?

Comment: When using version control, the diff to the previous version looks cleaner if another entry is added (in general cases). You just get a new line. If the comma is missing, you get a removed line and two added lines (one changed line, one added line).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trailing comma after the last `enum` member is optional. This was presumably done to aid automatic code generation which can just spit out stuff without thinking about the grammar.

Whether the comma is present or not doesn't change anything.

Take a look at the grammar:

> *enum-declaration:*
>   *attributes*<sub>*opt*</sub> *enum-modifiers*<sub>*opt*</sub> `enum` *identifier* *enum-base*<sub>*opt*</sub> *enum-body* `;`<sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> *enum-base:*
>   `:` *integral-type*
>
> *enum-body:*
>   `{`   *enum-member-declarations*<sub>*opt*</sub>   `}`
>   `{`   *enum-member-declarations*   `,`   `}`
>
> *enum-member-declarations:*
>   *enum-member-declaration*
>   *enum-member-declarations* `,` *enum-member-declaration*
>
> *enum-member-declaration:*
>   *attributes*<sub>*opt*</sub> *identifier*
>   *attributes*<sub>*opt*</sub> *identifier* `=` *constant-expression*

As you see, the *enum-body* includes the option of a single trailing comma.

Comment: Wasn't so fast with the grammar. Formatting is a pain :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure no day of week is missing.. :)

You can have an optional comma at the end of an enum definition (works without as well). I guess that's just a convenience thing: If the world changes and you have to add a day to the week: Add a new line (and optionally end it with a comma again, for the next guy defining new days).

Comment: I dunno, looks like they missed BlarkDay in that enum ;)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler just ignores the last comma. It doesn't need to be there, but it's not an error either if you put it